# How to check if 'ARGV' contains both '-p' and '-c' in optparse

Tags: ruby, optparse

This code is intended to check whether the user entered an option with the command:

```
require 'optparse'

ARGV << '-h' if ARGV.empty?    
options = {}    
OptionParser.new do |parser|
  parser.banner = "Usage: myruby.rb [options]"
  parser.on("-h", "--help", "Help myruby") do | |
    puts parser
    exit
  end
  parser.on("-p", "--people PEOPLE", "PPPPPPPPPP") do |v|
    options[:pppp] = v
  end
  parser.on("-c", "--coordinate COORDINATE", "ccccccccc") do |x|
    options[:coordinate] = x
  end
end.parse!
# Start my program from this line 
unless options[:pppp] && options[:coordinate]
  puts "Exit OK because missing both (option and argument) p,c"
  exit
end
puts "It work if only run myruby.rb -p argument_P -c argument_c"
```

I just found an error. If the user enters only one but not both required `ARGV (-p -c)`.
I can check and exit from my application, but I want to filter `ARGV` by exiting to assign `ARGV << 'h'`.

What is the best way?

> updated 1: Added unless case before run my program problem : Worked as
>   asked, but error when -p or -c missing argument. example : ruby
>   thiscode.rb -p bababa -c  error   : rb:17:in `': missing
>   argument (OptionParser::MissingArgument)

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation. "required arguments" means that your option (e.g. `-p`) requires an argument (i.e. `-p 123`). So _if_ the option is provided, it has to be provided with an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just explicitly check the presence of both after options are parsed:

```
unless options[:pppp] && options[:coordinate]
  puts USAGE # or do whatever else
  exit
end
```

Comment: Great it work. But it just exit. I like to let go run with help with ARGV = -h if possible then user know what to do.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. There is no magic behind `ARGV = -h`, it is parsed as everything else and prints usage line. Just print usage line on your own as shown in my example.

Comment: @mudasobwa : The magic is not in the option, but in the `parser.to_s` method.

Comment: @user1934428 then assign `parser = OptionParser.new ...` and do `puts parser` instead of `puts USAGE`, I don’t see any issue here.

Comment: @T.Kul : You need to achieve the effect of the `puts parser` statement in you treatment of `-h` outside of the block which deals with the options. I haven't tried it, but I this this should work: Instead of doing a `parse!` on your parser, assign it to a variable `myparser=....`. Then get the helptext by `helptext=myparser.to_s`. Then do a `myparser.parse!`.

Comment: @mudasobwa : It's not an issue. It's just something we had to tell the OP, because he didn't realize that it can be done in this way. Actually I see from your posting that it can be done even simpler as I had suggested. No temporary *helptext* variable needed.

Comment: I updated in my question. It worked upon my first issue. I found another problem when user provide option -p or -c but not argument then error ruby line ?? which not look good. Any suggestion.

Comment: Please ask one question per post as it’s stated in the ToS. If you have another question, post another one separately.